# spring data ldap: LdapRespository - how to find user by DN?

Tags: spring-data, spring-ldap

I might not understand how the spring data ldap LdapRepository works but I'm confused because, I don't know how to find an LDAP user by DN.
For example, a user in my directory looks like:

```
dn: uid=nicolas,ou=mycompany,dc=com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: top
cn: nicolas
sn: nicolas
uid: nicolas
userPassword: $2a$12$qIaTIG3UVm0hfKRWbwO5EueXG.omG7FL0XmuVxlQ8UuJrozX8Tlk2
```

In a Spring Boot REST controller I get the current authenticated user like this:

```
   Map principal = (Map)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
   String dn = principal.get("dn");
```

Here the "dn" string is "uid=nicolas,ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com"

The user class is as follows:

```
@Entry(base = "ou=people", objectClasses = {"top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson", "simpleSecurityObject"})
public class RdfLdapUser
{
  @Id
  private Name id;

  @Attribute(name = "uid")
  private String uid;

  @Attribute(name = "cn")
  private String cn;

  @Attribute(name = "sn")
  private String sn;

  @Attribute(name = "dn")
  private String dn;
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RdfLdapRepository extends LdapRepository<RdfLdapUser>
{
  public Optional<RdfLdapUser> findByUid (String uid);
  public Optional<RdfLdapUser> findByDn (String dn);
}
```

Trying to find an user by its DN which is "uid=nicolas,ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com" raises the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.setupEnvironment(SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.java:42)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.setupAuthenticatedEnvironment(AbstractContextSource.java:194)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getAuthenticatedEnv(AbstractContextSource.java:582)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:134)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:158)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:357)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:578)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1840)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1861)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.findOne(LdapTemplate.java:1869)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

The other thing is that there is an annotation @DnAttribute which I don't understand the meaning. The documentation says:

> Indicates that a field is to be automatically populated to/from the distinguished name of an entry. Fields annotated with this annotation will be automatically populated with values from the distinguished names of found entries. For automatic calculation of the DN of an entry to work, the index() value must be specified on all DnAttribute annotations in that class, and these attribute values, prepended with the Entry.base() value will be used to figure out the distinguished name of entries to create and update.

I simply don't get it. I've seen examples like that:

```
@DnAttribute(value="uid", index=0)
private String uid;
```

but I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean. It's saying that the the DN it's the uid index 0. For me, the DN is the DN and the uid is the uid and I dont understand what does it mean that the DN is the uid. Could someone please clarify ?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: The LDIF shows the following `dn: uid=nicolas,ou=mycompany,dc=com`, so how could you perform a search with base dn 'ou=people,ou=mycompany,dc=com' ? This entry is not a parent entry of the 'user entry'. It may not even exist in your LDAP Directory Server.

Comment: Not related to my question but, to satisfy your curiosity, then yes, the correct dn before obfuscating it for publication purposes, contained ou=people. Any suggestion concerning my issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I am here after one year and hope I can help yet. I would like to explain how @DnAttribute works at the beginning.

[image: Group mapping]

When you will try to save an entity looks like in the picture, you need to set attributes like in every other case, despite the @DnAttribute are @Transient, so they are not mirrored in the LDAP, @DnAttribute causes composing DN. Base DN is set into LdapContextSource.

[image: LdapContext]

For example when Base DN = "DC=company,DC=com", then you set the DN attributes into entity:

- firstLevelOu = "firstLevelOu",
- company = "ourCompany",
- secondLevelOu = "secondLevelOu",
- name = "newGroup"

DN of the record stored in the LDAP will look like: "CN=newGroup,OU=secondLevelOu,OU=ourCompany,OU=firstLevelOu,DC=company,DC=com"

When you want to get this group from LDAP, you only need LdapRepository, method **findById()**:

[image: find by id]

You only need pass into method relative DN, base DN is set implicitly, so relative DN is **CN=newGroup,OU=secondLevelOu,OU=ourCompany,OU=firstLevelOu**

**EDIT**

LdapAdapterUtils.createLdapName:

```java
import org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils;

public final class LdapAdapterUtils {

    public static LdapName createLdapName(String relativeDN) throws BadRequestAppException {

        LdapName createdName;
        try {
            createdName = LdapUtils.newLdapName(relativeDN);
        } catch (InvalidNameException e) {
            throw new BadRequestAppException("Relative DN: " + relativeDN + "is not valid DN");
        }
        return createdName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Peter, could you explain where the LdapAdapterUtils come from?

Comment: @GaborGarami I added the method declaration. :)